# How to add verbosity option to control script output?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to add kind of a 'verbosity' option in my script for users.
That is, when user adds `-v` as an argument to my script, script should spit out everything a command normally does, on `stdout`. If there is no `-v` , then nothing should be printed on `stdout` except what i manually `echo` to inform users about the running command.

Here is my idea and implementation -

1. Have a variable `V` appended at the end of each command in the script-
   like `dd if=/dev/zero of=${XYZ} bs=1M count=5 ${V}`
2. Check for the `-v` option from the user, if its NOT present then assign `/dev/null` to `V` otherwise `V` is null any way.

Script snippet :

```
V=">/dev/null"
while getopts "v" opt; do
 case $opt in
 v) V="" ;;
 esac
done

dd if=/dev/zero of=${XYZ} bs=1M count=5 ${V}
```

So, i'm expecting that when `V` is set to `/dev/null`, `dd` command wont print anything otherwise `V` is null anyway so command will print the usual stuff it prints.

**Problem:**
When i'm running the script, command `dd` (or any other command for that matter) treats `${V}` as an argument and complains about not understanding it
`Creating Disk Image:dd: unrecognized operand ‘>/dev/null’`

What more confuses me is when i hard code `/dev/null` in `dd` command
`dd if=/dev/zero of=${XYZ} bs=1M count=5 >/dev/null` , it runs as expected (i.e. no output print).

It would be greatly appreciated if anyone could throw some light on the said behaviour and suggest accordingly.

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot store re-direction operators in variables and expect it to work!

Comment: ahhh... right. Thanks @Inian for pointing out. So now the whole idea fails. 
Could you please suggest some approach.
 I know this(redirection problem) could be avoided using `sh -c "command"` trick but it would be very dirty to do it for each command in the script.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to silence output (`stdout`), run:

```
exec >/dev/null
```

If you want to silence some commands but not others, save a copy of stdout and redirect as wanted:

```
exec 6>&1         # Save current stdout as file handle 6
exec >/dev/null   # Silence stdout
date              # This command is silenced
exec >&6          # Restore stdout to its original destination
echo Hi           # This command will display
```

#### Sample script

```
#!/bin/bash

# Save current stdout as file handle 6 and then set for silence
exec 6>&1
exec >/dev/null

# Process options
while getopts "v" opt; do
 case "$opt" in
 v) exec >&6 ;;
 esac
done

# Generate output
echo "Information out"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is easier to use the variable in a different way, and always pipe the output of every command to a handler. For example:

```
handle_out() {
    $V
}

while getopts "v" opt; do
 case $opt in
 v) V=cat ;;
 esac
done

dd if=/dev/zero of=${XYZ} bs=1M count=5 | handle_out
```

Note that, if the "v" option is not specified, then $V in the `handle_out` function is empty. This causes handle_out to act as a data sink. If the "v" option is specified, then `handle_out` calls `cat`, which just sends the output to STDOUT.

Comment: `read` doesn't accept data on STDIN. And your last line won't work because it doesn't have a dollar sign on the variable name.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Whether or not `read` is able to use data on `STDIN` doesn't matter, as it is just being used as a data sink. I could also have used an empty function. Either way, it just makes the output go away. On the last line, `handle_out` is not a variable, it is an alias. Is there some other variable you are talking about?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `alias` on the first line. The fact that you're using `read` as a data sink is an interesting technique and worthy of being pointed out. However, in order for a script (a non-interactive shell) to use aliases, `shopt -s expand_aliases` needs to be included.

Comment: It's worth noting that when `$V` is null or unset it acts like a data sink.

Comment: Exactly, @DennisWilliamson